# Microsoft Graph Api - request not working

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I was trying to fetch users from an Azure Ad application. With some research I found how to do that. I realized that I needed an authentication provider, so I followed a this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS) that showed me how to choose the right one.

I tried with a client secret provider, but when I tried making a request using my `GraphServiceClient`, my program keeps closing with no errors. I tried different request like : `await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync()` or `await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync()`. Every time I make a request it fails.

I also tried using a Username/password provider with my credentials hard coded, but when I tried making a request my program closed again.

What am I doing wrong?

This is what I have right now:

```
        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
        };

        //var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(TenantId, ClientId, secret, options);

        var userName = "myUserName";
        var password = "myPassword";

        var creds = new UsernamePasswordCredential(userName, password, TenantId, ClientId, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(creds, scopes);

        try
        {
            var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem!

It was regarding permissions, I added the wrong permissions.
I added `Delegated permissions`, but I needed to add `Application permissions`.
Since I wanted to see all users and groups I added those application permissions: `Group.Read.All`, `GroupMember.Read.All` and `User.Read.All`.

Thanks to @Tiny Wang, I knew that my error wasn't in the code, but elsewhere.

**Edit**

Forgot to say but I also changed `await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync()` to `graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync().Result` to make it work.

Comment: `await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync()` will be better

Answer (score 0):

Please create a new asp.net core MVC project, then install `Azure.Identity` and `Microsoft.Graph` nuget package.

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_app_client_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: That's exactly how I did it and it wasn't working. But tenantId isn't de Directory (tenant) id?

Comment: Just tried putting my tenant name and it throwed me an exception while creating the ClientSecretCredential.